# mysql combine select from 3 tables with one different column

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 similar tables with 1 different column

```
id | user_id | post_id | other_id | favorite(tinyint) | date

id | user_id | post_id | other_id | like(tinyint) | date

id | user_id | post_id | other_id | comment(tinyint) | date
```

Is there a way to return all combined where user_id = 1 and order by date ?

Comment: Can you explain more specifically what you want to show in this column where the column of the underlying tables is different?

Comment: How are these tables related to each other. It is obvious you have users and posts. These are tables with booleans and dates but how are the liked posts and farorited posts related to the comment boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id, user_id, post_id, other_id, 'favorite' as type, date FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT id, user_id, post_id, other_id, 'like' as type, date FROM table2
UNION
SELECT id, user_id, post_id, other_id, 'comment' as type, date FROM table3
) AS t ORDER BY date
```

Comment: You should always use `union all`, unless you explicitly want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.